# How to encrypt a string using node.js?

Tags: encryption, node.js

I need a node.js equivalent of the following Ruby code:

```
    require 'openssl'
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
    signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, 'auth secret', 'some string')
```

I tried the following in node.js, but the Ruby signature is different from node's

```
    var crypto, signature;
    crypto = require('crypto');
    signature = crypto.createHash("sha1").update('auth secret').update('some string').digest("hex");
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497135/node-js-and-crypto-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You need to use the crypto#createHmac method instead of createHash, and pass it your secret (key) when creating it. This will give you what you're looking for:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
  , hmac
  , signature;

hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha1", 'auth secret');
hmac.update('some string');

signature = hmac.digest("hex");
```