# Node.js Crypto class returning different results with updated version

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes

The following code produces HTML output for a single-sign-on button that gets added to a page. In node version 0.5.x the key is accepted by the server on button click, but after upgrading to 0.10.x it does not work and produces a different output. No errors. Has the crypto class changed? Note, the key, url, and iv have been changed slightly to avoid posting secure information, but are the correct length.

```
var util = require('util');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');


var AESCrypt = {};


AESCrypt.encrypt = function(cryptkey, iv, cleardata) {

    var encipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', cryptkey, iv),
        encryptdata  = encipher.update(cleardata);


    encryptdata += encipher.final('binary');

    encode_encryptdata = new Buffer(encryptdata, 'binary').toString('hex');
    return encode_encryptdata;
}


function getKey(email){
  var now = new Date();
  var key = new Buffer("F4553ECE8E0039675E8DA176D23BD82D455BB6272B574FDD6185296432CE1AD9",'hex'),
    iv  = new Buffer("D95897EA52A8A0C8DF231C8F2DBE59A7",'hex'),
    key_bin = key.toString('binary'),
    iv_bin = iv.toString('binary'),
    text = new Buffer('mystring','ascii'),
    text_bin = text.toString('binary');

  var enc  = AESCrypt.encrypt(key_bin, iv_bin, text_bin);

  var page = '<form method="POST" action="https://somedomain.com/AES.aspx"><input type="hidden" name="key" value="'+enc+'"/><input type="hidden" name="ouid" value="1"/><input type="submit" value="Log ine"/></form>';

  return page;
}

if(process.argv[2]) {
    email = process.argv[2];
    console.log(getKey(email));
}
else{
    console.log('Something may be wrong with your email address>')
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Buffer.concat` instead of +=? I answered another question where `+=` did not work correctly.

Comment: Hello, did you try this already?

Comment: Sorry, yes this worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that - at least for later versions of NodeJS - that `Buffer.concat()` is required instead of the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Woking code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var ecr = function(str)
{
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'passphase');
    var cryptedBuffers = [cipher.update(new Buffer(str))];
    cryptedBuffers.push(cipher.final());
    var crypted = Buffer.concat(cryptedBuffers);
    return crypted;
};
var dcr = function(str)
{
    var dcipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', 'passphase');

    var dcryptedBuffers = [dcipher.update(new Buffer(str))];
    dcryptedBuffers.push(dcipher.final());
    var dcrypted = Buffer.concat(dcryptedBuffers)
        .toString('utf8');
    return dcrypted;
};

console.log(dcr(ecr('hello test')));
```