# Node.js Crypto cipher special characeters

Tags: node.js, encryption, node-crypto

I am trying to field level encrypt data in Node using the crypto library.

It seems to work just fine, except with special characters like $ and -

Ex "Price-Smith"

Not sure why

```
function encrypt(data, key) {
    if (data === null)
        return null
    else if (typeof data === 'undefined')
        return undefined;
    else if (data === '')
        return '';

    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'binary');
    return Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.final()]).toString('base64');
}

function decrypt(cipher, key) {
    if (cipher === null)
        return null
    else if (typeof cipher == 'undefined')
        return undefined;
    else if (cipher === '')
        return '';

    var cipher = new Buffer(cipher, 'base64');
    var iv = cipher.slice(0, 16);
    var ciphertext = cipher.slice(16);

    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    decipher.update(ciphertext, 'binary', 'utf8');
    return decipher.final('utf8');
}
```

Error

```
TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
at Decipheriv.Cipher.final (crypto.js:287:27)
```

A separate IV is used for each field value, otherwise fields values that are the same would have the same cipher. So I store the IV as the first 16 bytes and splice it off before decryption. Maybe this could be my problem area?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the size of the plaintext rather than the type of characters used. You need to concatenate the response from `update()` with the response from `final()`. Don't use `+=` operator, it [does not always work on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20484683/589259).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @owlstead! Here is the working code:

```
function encrypt(data, key) {
    if (data === null)
        return null
    else if (typeof data === 'undefined')
        return undefined;
    else if (data === '')
        return '';

    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    var encrypted = [cipher.update(data)];
    encrypted.push(cipher.final());

    return Buffer.concat([iv, Buffer.concat(encrypted)]).toString('base64');
}

function decrypt(cipher, key) {
    if (cipher === null)
        return null
    else if (typeof cipher == 'undefined')
        return undefined;
    else if (cipher === '')
        return '';

    var cipher = new Buffer(cipher, 'base64');
    var iv = cipher.slice(0, 16);
    var ciphertext = cipher.slice(16);

    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    var decrypted = [decipher.update(ciphertext)];
    decrypted.push(decipher.final());

    return Buffer.concat(decrypted).toString('utf8');
}
```