# Encryption & Encoding(AES, UTF-8 and base64)code conversion from JAVA to node.js giving different results

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, node-crypto

> Update : I finally managed to recreate the whole Java code as required for the third party service. I must add that some of the libraries used are deprecated but I cannot do anything because that is what the other side is using and I must comply.

**Java Code**

```
   SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),
    "AES");
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
   cipher.init(1, secretKeySpec);

   byte[] aBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes());
```

Input Key : xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy
Input Text: maryhadalittlelamb

> Output :
>   Z22GETg3Anl92%2BoyqdVWs9haQveaZxkDn8sQYP08iCY%3D

**node.js Code**

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', key);
var encryptedPassword = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');
encryptedPassword += cipher.final('base64');
console.log(encryptedPassword);
```

Input Key : xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy
Input Text: maryhadalittlelamb

> Output: mnqrpA2eqAhmseTrkBtH3YSGMoFs+ECPUamVd8/bgAQ=

The output for same inputstring and key is different for both. In fact the node.js is different but the base64 one looks identical nevertheless.

I am fairly new to these things therefore I have lost my may.

Comment: you need to find out exactly what `SecretKeySpec` outputs. if you give each aes core the same key bytes and choose the same key size and mode, they should be compatible. aside: ecb is a weak mode, use something better if possible.

Comment: @dandavis The java code belongs to third party service which isn't under my control therefore I'll have to send the data the way they want. What and How do I need to check  with/in `SecretKeySpec`;

Comment: i'm guessing it a KDF, and you'll need to be able to reproduce the input>output in node for the aes to use the same actual keys on both environments.

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. This is wrong: `String doc2 = new String(aBytes, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @ArtjomB. - Updated the question please have a look.

Comment: Can you summarize the edit for me? Did the linked duplicate answer help? If not, what was the problem? If I understood you correctly, it seems you want translate your Java code to node.js. The first step to do this is to use `createCipheriv` instead of `createCipher`. That's the main point in the linked duplicate answer.

Comment: I have a text and a key @ArtjomB. what shall I take as IV? If I use any random string for IV, I guess the values wont stay the same.

Comment: Have you read my answer? There is no IV for ECB mode, so you can either pass an empty `Buffer` or an empty string as the IV.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the issue? The only thing that you're missing is the URL-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In node.js you base64 encode the input string before you encrypt, it needs to be the **output** from the encrypt that needs to be base64 encoded.

Also, you need a call to `cipher.final(..)` after `cipher.update(..)` to finish off the encryption operation. Remember to capture the output from both.

In addition to this please note that [ECB mode is insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29).

Comment: Arhh .. turns out that the `final(..)` methode in js don't accepts data to encrypt (as it do in java) .. so you both need an update(..) and a final(...) call in js

Comment: Thanks Ebbe M. for your time, really appreciated. Still not working though. http://pastebin.com/ap4Dk1ti Please have a look at this pastebin, let me know if I have done something wrong.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247806/node-js-crypto-class-returning-different-results-with-updated-version)

Comment: I have updated the code based upon the thread you shared. Please have a look. I have even tried to recreate the Java Code because the third party service's demo code has outdated base64encoder.

Comment: Please let me know if my recreating of the same code is okay or not. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question. Please check.